# Let $X = S^1 \times S^1$ and let $p_1,p_2,p_3 \in S^1$ and let $A =....$. Compute $H_i(X,A)$ $\forall i$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X = S^1 \times S^1$ and let $p_1,p_2,p_3$ be distinct points in $S^1$ and let $A = (S^1 \times \{p_1\}) \cup (S^1 \times \{p_2\}) \cup (S^1 \times \{p_3\})$

Compute $H_i(X,A)$ $\forall i$.

We have a L.E.S.:

$$0 \rightarrow H_2(A) \stackrel{h}{\rightarrow} H_2(X) \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} H_2(X,A) \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} H_1(A) \stackrel{e}{\rightarrow} H_1(X) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}$$ $$ H_1(X,A) \stackrel{c}{\rightarrow} H_0(A) \stackrel{b}{\rightarrow} H_0(X) \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} H_0(X,A) \rightarrow 0$$

We can easily compute the following:

$H_2(A) = 0$

$H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z}$

$H_1(A) = \mathbb{Z}^3$

$H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}^2$

$H_0(A) = \mathbb{Z}^3$

$H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$

Furthermore, I have concluded that $H_0(X,A) = 0$, since $b$ is a surjective map.

Also, $g$ is injective so $ker(f)=im(g)=H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z}$

Also, I was thinking that $im(f)=ker(e)=\mathbb{Z}$, but am not sure and would like to know how to think about this more rigorously.

And so I thought that maybe $H_2(X,A)=ker(f) \oplus im(f) = \mathbb{Z}^2$, but I'm not sure.

And I'm quite lost for $H_1(X,A)$.

Insight appreciated!!

Comment: Surely $H_1(A)\cong\Bbb Z^3$?

Comment: Hmm,, really? I thought it would be $\mathbb{Z}$. I gave it a CW-structure with a 0-cell and a one-cell forming $S^1$, and then three other vertices floating out in space. This is wrong thinking?

Comment: Looks like three disjoint circles to me....

Comment: Well, Think of $X = S^1 \times S^1$ as the Torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then in each union, we the copy of S^1 is always the same S^1, and we are just picking up another point "floating around" the meridian.

Comment: Still looks like three disjoint circles to me, all giving the same element of $H_1(S^1\times S^1)$....

Comment: Would you say that in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, the $x$-axis $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ is the same as the horizontal line $\mathbb R \times \{1\}$ and the horizontal line $\mathbb R \times \{2\}$? So we are just picking up another point "floating around" the $y$-axis?

Comment: Given sets $A$ and $B$ we have the product $A\times B$ defined as the set of all ordered pairs $(a, b)$ such that $a\in A $ and $b\in B$. Moreover, two ordered pairs $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ are equal iff $a=c$ and $b=d$.  If $b_0 \neq b_1$ then $A\times \{b_0\}$ and $ A\times \{b_1\}$ are disjoint, because if $(a, b)$ were in the intersection then $b_0 = b = b_1$. This is why your three circles are all disjoint if the $p_i$'s are distinct.

Comment: That's interesting... So $S^1 \times S^1$ has an infinite number of circles inside of it?? $S^1 \times \{p_1\}, S^1 \times \{p_2\},....$

I mean I get what you are all saying, yet I am confused. I'm sure it has something to do with the way to visualize $S^1 \times S^1$ geometrically is not like homology invariant or something... What I mean is if you picture $S^1 \times S^1$ as the torus, then if we use the meridian as the first copy of $S^1$, then $S^1 \times \{p_1\}, S^1 \times \{p_2\}$ seem to be the one circle with different points floating around it... Yet if we take the first copy

Comment: The first copy of $S^1$ to be the parallel circles, then $S^1 \times \{p_1\}, S^1 \times \{p_2\}$ seem to be two disjoint circles. Hmmm....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lord Shark is correct in the comments: $A\cong S^1 \sqcup S^1 \sqcup S^1$ (as long as the $p_i$'s are all distinct), so $H_1(A) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3\cong H_0(A)$. Moreover the images of each of these circles in $H_1(X)$ are homologous, and can be described by the Kunneth theorem as $u\otimes 1$ where $u$ is the generator of $H_1(S^1)$.  The kernel of $e$ is then the set of all $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ such that $x+y+z = 0$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and the kernel of $b$ is similarly described. Now we have

$$ 0 \stackrel{h}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{g}{\to} H_2(X, A) \stackrel{f}{\to} \mathbb{Z}^3 \stackrel{e}{\to} \mathbb{Z}^2 \stackrel{d}{\to} H_1(X, A) \stackrel{c}{\to} \mathbb{Z}^3 \stackrel{b}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$

To help us compute the unknown groups, here's a helpful lemma you should verify as an exercise:

> **Lemma:** Suppose we have a long exact sequence of abelian groups
>   $$\dots \to A \stackrel{a}{\to} B\stackrel{b}{\to} C \stackrel{c}{\to} D \stackrel{d}{\to} E \stackrel{}{\to} \dots $$
>   then there is a short exact sequence
>   $$0 \to coker(a) \to C \to im(c) \to 0 $$

Using this lemma we can isolate $H_1(X,A)$ with the short exact sequence

$$0 \to coker(e) \to H_1(X, A) \to im(c) \to 0 $$

By the above discussion, $im(c) = ker(b)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and also $im(e)$ is one of the $\mathbb{Z}$ summands of $H_1(X)$ so $coker(e)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, so $H_1(X,A)$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence must be $\mathbb{Z}^3$ by the [Splitting Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) since any surjective homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has a section (because it is a free abelian group and hence projective). Similarly we can isolate $H_2(X, A)$ with

$$ 0 \to coker(h) \to H_2(X, A) \to im(f) \to 0$$

and again $coker(h) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $im(f) = ker(e)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ so again $H_2(X, A)\cong \mathbb{Z}^3$.

Comment: How do you know $c$ is the zero map? I guess because you knew $H_0(A) \cong H_0(X)$... I thought $H_0(A) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$.. oops.

Comment: Man i'm so bad at this baby homological algebra stuff (which is what this time of reasoning is, correct?) I never know when I can consider a group the product of its kernel and image.

Also, i'm not familiar with the Kunneth Theorem. Is there another way to think about this possibly?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom You just need to know the map $e: H_1(A) \rightarrow H_1(X)$ is the inclusion and each generator of $H_1(A)$ is homologous in $H_1(X)$ since $A$ is just a circle and its union with two translates. To see the image is $\mathbb{Z}$ (this is why he initially mentioned the Kunneth theorem) you must know what the generators of $H_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}^2 $ are. You can do this through simplicial homology. Then you see the inclusion $A \rightarrow X$ just induces an inclusion of one of the factors.

Comment: Yeah, I need to remember that when trying to figure out what's going on in an LES that I have more than just exactness to work with,

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Yes you're completely correct and I made a mistake: $H_0(A)\cong \mathbb{Z}^3$! I updated my answer with this correction, I think it looks more right now.

Comment: I also added a lemma which might help you out in the future

Comment: With regards to your question about "when can you write the thing in the middle as a product of the outer things" this is studied with the theory of [group extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension). There is a nice result called the "[Splitting Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma)" which applies to abelian groups and says that a short exact sequence of abelian groups splits iff the middle group is a direct sum of the outer groups. One powerful tool for this problem is the [Ext functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Properties_of_Ext).

Comment: In our particular case, we have short exact sequences of the form $0\to A \to B \to \mathbb{Z}^k \to 0$. I'm using the facts that i) $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [projective module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module#Split-exact_sequences) and that ii) projective modules are closed under direct sums, to deduce that our sequence splits and hence $B \cong A \oplus \mathbb{Z}^k$.

Comment: I realized that we don't need the full generality of projective modules here: a short exact sequence $A\to B \stackrel{p}{\to} \mathbb{Z}^k$ splits because $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is *free*. Specifically, for each generator $g_1,\dots,g_k\in \mathbb{Z}^k$ pick an element $b_i \in p^{-1}(g_i) \subset B$ and then by the universal property for a free object the assignment $g_i \mapsto b_i$ defines a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^k \to B$ which is a section of $p$. (In fact this is a proof that $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is projective.)

Comment: Cool. So since the last term in the S.E.S. is a free group, you can consider the middle term to be a direct product of the first and third one.

Comment: Yes. In fact, more explicitly, if we have a s.e.s. $A\stackrel{i}{\to} B \stackrel{p}{\to} \mathbb{Z}^k$ then we can construct a section $s\colon \mathbb{Z}^k \to B$ of $p$ as above, and an isomorphism $\varphi_s\colon A\oplus \mathbb{Z}^k \cong B$ is given by $\varphi_s(a, v) = i(a) + s(v)$.

Comment: Here's where the buzzword "projective" is convenient, because $P$ is projective iff every surjective homomorphism $B \to P$ has a section (and it is a fact that free abelian groups are projective abelian groups). Then every s.e.s. of abelian groups $A\to B \to P$ will have a splitting $P \to B$, inducing an isomorphism $A\oplus P \cong B$ by the Splitting Lemma.

Comment: So if the first term in the S.E.S. is free abelian then the sequence will split by a similar argument?

Comment: No: consider the sequence $\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$. The appropriate type of object for a splitting on the left is an [injective module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module) (the basic example of an injective abelian group is $\mathbb{Q}$).